# Como fixar "corpos" rígidos utilizando PhysX

Tags: c++, opengl, constraint, physx

Como posso fixar dois "corpos" rígidos ou dinâmicos de uma maneira que onde um vá o outro vá junto o mais fixo possível com **PhysX**.

Eu estou utilizando a classe `PxFixedJoint` mas não me agradou.

[image: PxFixedJoint]

Como podem ver no print a cima, existe uma curva "barriga" na formação dos cubos.
 Eu já pesquisei mas não encontrei nada de concreto. Queria uma solução para fixar os objetos uns aos outros mas com o mínimo de curva (por assim dizer).

Abaixo um trecho do código.

```
// C++
// Função responsável por criar o joint
void HEntity::createFixedJoint(HEntity* target)
{
    physx::PxPhysics* physics = HEngine::getInstance()->getPhysicsContext()->getPhysics();
    physx::PxRigidActor* _target = target->getPhysicsBody();

    physx::PxVec3 pos_a = m_pPhysicsBody->getGlobalPose().p;
    physx::PxVec3 pos_b = _target->getGlobalPose().p;
    physx::PxVec3 offset = (pos_a - pos_b).abs() / 2;

    physx::PxFixedJoint* joint = physx::PxFixedJointCreate(*physics, m_pPhysicsBody, physx::PxTransform(-offset), _target, physx::PxTransform(offset));

    joint->setConstraintFlag(physx::PxConstraintFlag::eVISUALIZATION, true);
    joint->setConstraintFlag(physx::PxConstraintFlag::eCOLLISION_ENABLED, false);

    m_lpJoints.push_back(joint);
}
```

Como estou utilizando `Lua Script` para a estender/ampliar minha aplicação, abaixo um trecho do script em `Lua` que cria os cubos.

```
-- Lua
-- Função responsável por criar os cubos em serie
function createJointCubes()
    local parent = scene:getObjectByName("Object.2") -- Cubo já presente na cena
    local last_obj = nil;

    for i = 1, 12 do
        local obj = HGameObject:new()
        obj:setName("Object_Phy." .. i)
        obj:setMesh(HEngine.importWavefront(imports[2]))

        if last_obj == nil then
            obj:setWorldPosition(parent:getWorldPosition()+HVec3(2, 0, 0))
        else
            obj:setWorldPosition(last_obj:getWorldPosition()+HVec3(2, 0, 0))
        end

        obj:createPhysicsBody()

        if last_obj == nil then
            obj:createFixedJoint(parent)
        else
            obj:createFixedJoint(last_obj)
        end

        scene:addObject(obj)
        last_obj = obj
    end
end
```

Comment: Não dá pra ter certeza pelo screenshot que você postou, mas essa curvatura não é resultado da gravidade aplicada à "corrente" formada pelos cubos? Se não, você chegou a tentar aumentar um pouco a distância entre os cubos em cada *joint*? (pois talvez o problema seja devido à colisão entre os cubos) Também, pra facilitar em receber ajuda, você poderia publicar um exemplo mínimo de código em que o problema é facilmente reproduzível.

Comment: @Luiz Vieira, eu já acrescentei mais informações a pergunta. Eu coloquei para que os cubos não colidam ente si. Existem alguns jogos que utilizam um sistema de construção de veículos utilizando blocos com física, que cada bloco tem uma massa diferente que altera a física do veículo no jogo. E mesmo assim essa tal curvatura parece não acontecer.

Comment: Legal. Mas, na cena, o cubo da esquerda parece estar mais pra cima no eixo Y (ou Z, dependendo da referência), não? Sério mesmo, você tem certeza que não é por causa da gravidade? Outra coisa, não sei como funciona agrupamento nessa biblioteca (sempre usei a Bullet ou embutidas em game engines), mas talvez você evite a "barriga" usando sub-estrutura ao invés de joint. Tipo, faça um próximo cubo ser "filho" do anterior. Assim, as propriedades da massa se mantêm, sem a interferência da junta móvel.

Comment: A respeito do cubo da esquerda estar mais pra cima, fiz de propósito. Fiz justamente para verificar se iria ocorrer o problema com a curvatura. O que seria essa sub-estrutura que você disse?. Enquanto isso estou pesquisando para encontrar uma solução.

Comment: Você disse para eu fazer um cubo ser "filho" do anterior, excelente ideia. Mas estou vasculhando a API da `PhysX` e não estou encontrando um meio de fazer esse tipo de ligação.

Comment: Pois então. Jutamente por isso que ocorre a "barriga". Pensa na estrutura final como uma corrente. Se você segura ela pelas pontas, a gravidade faz com que os itens do meio formem uma [catenária](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caten%C3%A1ria). Pra evitar isso, desligue a gravidade ou não use juntas, modelando o objeto de forma única ou agrupando-os. Como eu disse, não sei como fazer no PhysX, mas deve ter um jeito. :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16130/discussion-between-luiz-vieira-and-walberti-evaristo).

Comment: Oi Walberti. Que bom que você resolveu! Mas, ao invés de ter editado a pergunta pra colocar a solução, seria melhor se você tivesse adicionado uma resposta você mesmo e a aceitado (assim a pergunta para de constar como não respondida). Por que você não faz isso? Adiciona uma resposta com a sua solução, e edita a questão pra remover isso dela. :)

Comment: @Luiz Vieira, pode parecer brincadeira, mas no dia em que eu fui editar para colocar a solução, eu procurei procurei o botão para responder a minha própria pergunta, mas não encontrei.

Comment: Sem problemas. Ah, valeu por colocar como resposta. Fica bem melhor. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **RESOLVIDO**

Bem, depois de pesquisar bastante, eu acabei encontrando uma solução na própria documentação da `PhysX`.

O que eu fiz foi "parentar" (tornar "filho") o objeto que eu queria (que no caso é estático) ao um objeto rigidbody (objeto afetado pela física) multiplicando a transformação do objeto "pai" pela a do "filho".

Depois eu usei o método [`attachShape`](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/apireference/files/classPxRigidActor.html#17c7ab7d692e4b3b8239216aa0d6eeb7) para adicionar o shape físico do "filho" a lista de shapes físicos do "pai" e, [atualizei a massa e inércia](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/apireference/files/classPxRigidBodyExt.html#b8f6af57a0fde875c41e5d747dec49fb).

```
// C++
// Acada frame ("Parentando")
m_FilhoWorldTransform =  m_pPai->getWorldTransform() * m_FilhoWorldTransform;
// ...
// Adicionando shape "filho" ao rigidbody "Pai"
m_pPai->getRigidBody()->attachShape(m_Filho->getShape());
// ...
// Atualizando massa e inércia
physx::PxU32 mass_count = 2; // Numero de shapes/massas
physx::PxReal* masses = new physx::PxReal[2];
masses[0] = pai_mass;
masses[1] = filho_mass;

physx::PxRigidBodyExt::setMassAndUpdateInertia(*parent->getRigidDynamic(), masses, mass_count);
delete masses;
```

E veja o resultado. Não tem mais "barriga". A física funciona corretamente, é como se os cubos fizessem parte do objeto "Pai".

[image: Resultado]